# How to create ghost agents based on agents from another rank in repast4py?

Tags: agent-based-modeling, repast-hpc, repast4py

I am trying to create an OrderBook agent that can be shared across all ranks. I can share the agent using mpi4py send and receive operations. But based on the documentation [here](https://repast.github.io/repast4py.site/guide/user_guide.html#_the_agent_classes) I am assuming `self.context.synchronize(restore_orderbook)` will create ghost agents in each rank  **but the program is showing `KeyError: 0`**. The agent created in rank 0 is not being copied to other ranks as ghost even after using `request_agents` function.

**Expected output:**

Orderbook is created on rank 0 and ghost copies are made on rank 1,2,3 using the OrderBook created in rank 0. Print orders as per the if else logic present in the `step` function.

**test2.py**

```
from typing import Dict, Tuple
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np
from dataclasses import dataclass

from repast4py import core, random, space, schedule, logging, parameters
from repast4py import context as ctx
import repast4py
from queue import Queue
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import random as rnd


order_count = 1000
items = np.arange(1, 101)
quantities = np.arange(1, 11)
start_date = datetime(2023, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime(2023, 1, 3)

item_values = np.random.choice(items, size=order_count)
qty_values = np.random.choice(quantities, size=order_count)
time_deltas = np.random.randint(0, int((end_date - start_date).total_seconds()), size=order_count)
date_values = [start_date + timedelta(seconds=int(delta)) for delta in time_deltas]

data = {
    'item': item_values,
    'qty': qty_values,
    'order_datetime': date_values
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).sort_values(by=['order_datetime'], ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True)
df['order_id'] = np.arange(1, order_count+1)
df['order_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['order_datetime'])
df['tick'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 + int((x['order_datetime'] - df['order_datetime'].min()).total_seconds()/173), axis=1)
df.to_csv('test_data.csv', index=False)


class OrderBook(core.Agent): 
    TYPE = 0
    def __init__(self, a_id: int, rank: int):
        super().__init__(id=a_id, type=OrderBook.TYPE, rank=rank)
        self.df = list(pd.read_csv('test_data.csv').to_records())
        # self.df['order_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(self.df['order_datetime'])
    
    def save(self) -> Tuple:
        return (self.uid, self.df)

    def get_order(self, tick):
        return rnd.choice(self.df)

    def update(self, data):
        self.df = data 

orderbook_cache = {}


def restore_orderbook(orderbook_data: Tuple):

    uid = orderbook_data[0]
    if uid[1] == OrderBook.TYPE:
        if uid in orderbook_cache:
            ob = orderbook_cache[uid]
        else:
            ob = OrderBook(uid[0], uid[1], uid[2])
            orderbook_cache[uid] = ob

        ob.df = orderbook_data[1]
        return ob

def create_agent(agent_data):
    uid = agent_data[0]
    book = OrderBook(uid[0], uid[2])
    book.df = agent_data[1]
    return book
            
class Model:

    def __init__(self, comm: MPI.Intracomm, params: Dict):
        self.context = ctx.SharedContext(comm)
        self.rank = comm.Get_rank()
        if self.rank == 0:
            book = OrderBook(1, 0)
            self.context.add(book)
            requests = []
            print(book.uid)

        else:
            requests = [((1,0,0), 0)]

        self.context.request_agents(requests, create_agent)

        
        self.runner = schedule.init_schedule_runner(comm)
        self.runner.schedule_repeating_event(1, 1, self.step)
        self.runner.schedule_stop(params['stop.at'])
        self.runner.schedule_end_event(self.at_end)
                
        
    def step(self):
        tick = self.runner.schedule.tick
        self.context.synchronize(restore_orderbook)
        
        if self.rank == 0 and tick < 25:
            for b in self.context.agents(OrderBook.TYPE):
                order = b.get_order(tick)
                print(self.rank, order)    
        elif self.rank == 1 and 25 <= tick < 50:
            for b in self.context.agents(OrderBook.TYPE):
                order = b.get_order(tick)
                print(self.rank, order)
        elif self.rank == 2 and 50 <= tick < 75:
            for b in self.context.agents(OrderBook.TYPE):
                order = b.get_order(tick)
                print(self.rank, order)
        elif self.rank == 3 and 75 <= tick < 100:
            for b in self.context.agents(OrderBook.TYPE):
                order = b.get_order(tick)
                print(self.rank, order)
    
    def at_end(self):
        print('simulation complete')

    def start(self):
        self.runner.execute()    
         
def run(params: Dict):
    global model
    model = Model(MPI.COMM_WORLD, params)
    model.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = parameters.create_args_parser()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    params = parameters.init_params(args.parameters_file, args.parameters)
    run(params)
```

**test.yaml**

```
random.seed: 42
stop.at: 100
orders.count: 1000
```

command to run

```
mpirun -n 4 python test2.py test.yaml
```

I think the ghost agents are not getting created with  `self.context.request_agents(requests, create_agent)`. Is this usage right?

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 136, in <module>
    run(params)
  File "test2.py", line 129, in run
    model.start()
  File "test2.py", line 124, in start
    self.runner.execute()    
  File "/home/vinay/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/repast4py/schedule.py", line 584, in execute
    self.schedule.execute()
  File "/home/vinay/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/repast4py/schedule.py", line 406, in execute
    self.executing_group.execute(self.queue)
  File "/home/vinay/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/repast4py/schedule.py", line 243, in execute
    interrupted = self.execute_evts(self.prioritized, queue)
  File "/home/vinay/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/repast4py/schedule.py", line 223, in execute_evts
    evt()
  File "/home/vinay/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/repast4py/schedule.py", line 60, in __call__
    self.evt()
  File "test2.py", line 108, in step
    for b in self.context.agents(OrderBook.TYPE):
  File "/home/vinay/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/repast4py/context.py", line 358, in agents
    return self._agents_by_type[agent_type].values().__iter__()
KeyError: 0
```

**Edit:** Working solution

I replaced

```
for b in self.context.agents(OrderBook.TYPE):
order = b.get_order(tick)
print(self.rank, order)
```

with

```
b  = self.context.ghost_agent((1,0,0))
order = b.get_order(tick)
print(self.rank, order)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that all the ranks must call `request_agents`. In your code rank 0 is not calling it and so the code hangs waiting for rank 0 to complete the call. In MPI, this is called a collective operation. This is also mentioned in the docs for `request_agents`

"This is a collective operation and all ranks must call it, regardless of whether agents are being requested by that rank. The requested agents will be automatically added as ghosts to this rank"

This is easy to overlook though. When there's a hang in an MPI program it's usually something like this.

I tried the code with this update,

```
   if self.rank == 0:
        book = OrderBook(1, 0)
        self.context.add(book)
        requests = []
        # print(book.uid)

    else:
        requests = [((1,0,0), 0)]
    
    self.context.request_agents(requests, create_agent)
```

and the `request_agents` call works. However, there's an issue in the create_agent call. The OrderBook constructor only takes 3 arguments but create_agent has 4.

Lastly, I'm not sure how well the pandas data frame will pickle and transfer across processes. That might work, but if you do get errors maybe try to pass the data frame as a list of lists or something like that.

Comment: I thought of using request_agents but it requires 'create_agent' function as a callable which might look similar to restore_agent function if we write it, so I got confused. Or if the restore_agent function in Zombies example is indeed the create_agent callable in  request_agent API? Are 'save' and 'restore_agent' reserved function names in repast4py and must be provided always?

Comment: Here's an example of request_agents from the unit tests. https://github.com/Repast/repast4py/blob/0cfb33460ed3bf5c49c51b32a6b31dab994dc680/tests/shared_obj_tests.py#L2158. You can ignore much of that but it does show what the arguments to the request_agents method should be.

Comment: Nick, I tried request_agent but the attempted code still doesn't seem to be working. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you edit your question with the latest code you are trying and the error stack trace. Without the stack trace it's impossible to know where it's going wrong.

Comment: Updated the code and issue.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect your question edits. Hope this helps.

Comment: I updated the code as suggested and also removed usage of pandas data frames and corrected the arguments of create_agent function. I am still getting KeyError: 0. Request agent is not creating ghost agents in other ranks. If I remove OrderBook.TYPE argument in  self.context.agents(OrderBook.TYPE) simulation complete but doesn't print anything from 1,2,3 ranks

Comment: Try using the self.context.ghost_agent to get the ghost. https://repast.github.io/repast4py.site/apidoc/source/repast4py.context.html#repast4py.context.SharedContext.ghost_agent

Comment: Finally, it works :) Is there way to get list of all ghost agents without having to specify agent uid?